# Can't login withing Symfony application with neither file storage, nor memcached

Tags: php, session, permissions, symfony

I created a Symofny project and was trying to login after using the tutorial to build a Login Form.

However, when I login in (as a logged out user, it works without problems), I'm getting a Symfony Exception

```
Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/www/project/www/app/../var/sessions/dev)
```

The folder exists and a `var_dump(is_writable('/var/www/project/www/app/../var/sessions/dev'))` returns true, so I don't know what the problem could be. I lo0oked into the folder. Files are getting generated but they are all empty. Like it can't write to the files. I even gave the files `777` rights and am still getting the error.

I thought it might could be because the user and group of the files/folders is `vagrant` but when I try to change that via

`chown project:www-data dev` I only get the error that the operation is not permitted. What exactly can I do?

**Updates**

Also, when accessing the `/config.php` to check if everything is correct with my configuration I only get a recommendation, not an error

> intl ICU version installed on your system (52.1) should match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (55.1)
>   In most cases you should be fine, but please verify there is no inconsistencies between data provided by Symfony and the intl extension. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15007 for an example of inconsistencies you might run into.

**UPDATE 2**
When I change the session save path to `/tmp` a session is created, and there are even contents in the file, but I'm getting a 502 error, with the following lines in the nginx log

`2016/07/17 19:29:59 [error] 508#508: *56 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.60.1, server: www.project.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "www.project.dev", referrer: "http://www.project.dev/login"`

**UPDATE 3**
After enabling debug log for nginx, [this is the output](http://pastebin.com/mbDdXQUn).

Comment: The ICU thing is a standard requirements notification. It is nothing to do with the issue reported. And you must: `sudo chown project:www-data dev`

Comment: Hey. Didn't write it, but did `chown` when being logged in as a user. So sudo didn't change anything.